# How can I get all the wordpress posts separately from each other?

Tags: wordpress, post

I'm using the twentyeleven default template and I use

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

To get the Posts.

What I want is to have this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="first">
    //first post
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
</div>
<div id="second">
    //second post
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
</div>
<div id="third">
    //third post
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
</div>
</div><!-- end wrapper -->
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use post-1 instead of first, post-2 instead of second, etc.?  If so, dead easy.  Create a variable that increments each time through the loop and tracks the number of posts.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php $count = 0; /* <- create the counter variable */?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php echo $count; /* <- prints the variable */ $count++; /* <- increments the counter */ ?>">
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>             
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>         
<?php else : ?>         
<?php endif; ?>
```

From your question I'm not sure if you realize that everything between the while and endwhile bits gets inserted into the HTML for every post.  That's why it's called "the loop."  It loops over that section until every post on the page has been displayed.

You may also want to [use the built-in post class function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/post_class) to add relevant classes to every post.  Here is the above with the post class function added:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php $count = 0; /* <- create the counter variable */?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php echo $count; $count++;?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>             
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>         
<?php else : ?>         
<?php endif; ?>
```